# How to configue _redirects file correctly for netlify?

Tags: redirect, netlify

I have a `_redirects` file:

```
/blog/index.html /blog/ 200
/index.html / 200
/careers/index.html /careers/ 200
/technologies/index.html /technologies/ 200
```

I want that when I type in the address bar `https://sitename.com/index.html` I was thrown to the `https://sitename.com/`. And apply this rule for each page. But that doesn't happen. Am I doing something wrong for the `_redirects` file?